# What is '-f option' in zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am trying to understand when is `.zshenv` source and in manual both in terminal and [online](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html) is mentioned that

> .zshenv is sourced on all invocations of the shell, unless the -f
>   option is set

However I can't find what this `-f` option is. My guess from context would be that it sets non-interactive mode for the shell but it is just a guess.

Comment: Just FYI: The online documentation you linked is quite old. (More than 21 years. It was converted to HTML in 1995 and some code examples in it show time stamps from 1991.) So, while most of it will probably still work today, it does not really repressent the capabilities of current versions of *zsh*.

Answer (score 2):

From `zsh --help`

> -f    equivalent to --no-rcs

`-f` (or `--no-rcs`) prevents the zsh startup files from being sourced.

This is equivalent to the `--norc` option in Bash.

Comment: It may be important to note that `/etc/zshenv` will always be sourced first, even if the `-f` option is set.